# Make Wordpress upload directory outside wordpress root with custom url

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the upload directory for Wordpress from `project.dev/wp-content/uploads` to `cdn.project.dev`

Where subdomain **cdn** has DocumentRoot:
`HostPath/project.dev/cdn` while Wordpress is located at `HostPath/project.dev/public_html`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you could try `define('UPLOADS', 'your_path_here')`, path to your `cdn.project.dev` should be absolute and accessible with `open_baesdir` if it's on

Comment: @Flyer check my comment on Sky answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to change default media upload location,you need to edit the `wp-config.php` file located in the root directory of your WordPress installation. If you want upload directory to be wp-content/files then you will need to place the following code in wp-config.php

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

If you want the upload directory to be outside wp-content, like project.dev/cdn then you need to set upload path in wp-config.php like this:

```
define( 'UPLOADS','project.dev/cdn' );
```

**For exstining images**:-

Copy all the exstining images of uploads folder to new folder which has set in the wp-config.php file.

The above information is only to Change the Default Media Upload Location.

For Details visit :[Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder)

Comment: It only changed upload directory to wpDIR/project.dev/cdn not outside Wordpress root.

Answer (score 0):

Open your wp-config.php file, locoed at the root of your WordPress installation, and add the following snippet:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'project.dev/cdn');
```

Make sure you add this code before the line:

```
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
```

Comment: This solution path can not be absolute. Check https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder

Comment: What about cdn.project.dev? Do posted media like images has source file related to?

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim Take a look: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114657/how-to-store-media-files-in-subdomain AND https://wordpress.org/support/topic/moving-media-to-subdomain